# How to pass a value through a variable to a function

Tags: python, google-maps

when I am passing values through list `(gpslatlist[1] and gpslonlist[2])` to `gmaps.directions()` I am getting below error.

```
Error
    directions_result = gmaps.directions(gpslatlist[1]  gpslonlist[1],"washington dc");
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But when I pass actual latitude and longitude to the same function it completes without any error.

`gmaps.directions` expects input values like

```
gmaps.directions ("latitude longitude", "latitude longitude")
```

Comment: You are missing a comma between `gpslatlist[1]` and `gpslonlist[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

With any third party api you must be very careful to read the documentation, and ensure that your code is calling the functions properly. Either use the two input method, or try to design your own decorator that takes in parameters the way  you want. Otherwise take a look at the api documentation here. Here is a GitHub repository which may contain proper code samples and documentation for the python google maps api. I am unsure if this is what you are using but I hope this helps.
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python